# Bugs with chaining CSS3 animations

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to chain CSS3 animations together, but they behave very weird sometimes. For example, in [this pen](http://codepen.io/silvenon/pen/018ff2d56e6ed5935a2b1ddefdf68a92), why won't the last animation start? I got it working before, but it doesn't anymore, and I used the same setup. The code I'm pasting here is a little bit simplified, but the animations are exactly the same:

HTML:

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 60px;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;

  animation-name: fadeIn, fall, elastic;
  animation-timing-function: ease, ease-in, ease-out;
  animation-duration: 1s, 0.5s, 0.5s;
  animation-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards, forwards, forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fall {
  0%   { transform: translateY(-100px); }
  100% { transform: translateY(0px); }
}

@keyframes elastic {
  0%   { transform: translateY(0px); }
  20%  { transform: translateY(60px); }
  40%  { transform: translateY(-20px); }
  60%  { transform: translateY(10px); }
  80%  { transform: translateY(-5px); }
  100% { transform: translateY(0px); }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm wrong... but it seems that this does not "chain" them since they play simultaneously. If that's the case, then the last one probably isn't working because you're already keyframeing `translateY` in the second animation.

Comment: You are right, you can not animate at the same time the same property

Comment: I'm chaining them because I'm using `animation-delay` to play them sequentially. Does that matter?

Comment: Actually, you're right, if animate a different property in that last set of keyframes, it works!